# Alternative to WITH RECURSIVE CLAUSE

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake DB does not support recursive with clause function , Need help me on how to achieve below query . Below query works well in Teradata

If any one also can help me to achieve using Python that would be great

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE RECURTEMP(ID,KCODE,LVL)
AS(SELECT ID, MIN(KCODE) AS KCODE,1
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY 1
UNION ALL
SELECT b.ID, trim(a.KCODE)|| ';'||trim(b.KCODE), LVL+1
FROM TABLE_A a
INNER JOIN RECURTEMP b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.KCODE > b.KCODE
)
SELECT * FROM RECURTEMP
```

![Result]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PsbK.jpg

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
ID VARCHAR2(50),
KCODE VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES  ('ABCD','K10');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES  ('ABCD','K53');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES  ('ABCD','K55');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES  ('ABCD','K56');

COMMIT;
```

OUTPUT as below

```
ID               KCODE          LEVEL  
--------------------------------------
ABCD             K10               1
ABCD             K53;K10           2
ABCD             K55;K10           2
ABCD             K56;K10           2
ABCD             K55;K53;K10       3
ABCD             K56;K53;K10       3
ABCD             K56;K55;K10       3
ABCD             K56;K55;K53;K10   4
```

Comment: I would be bold to say that currently this is "impossible" (without much effort) within Snowflake DB given that you don't know the depth of recursion. You can keep on joining though, if the hierarchy level is not unknown. That would mimic the functionality but is bound by the code. You could probably create a procedure to establish the depth of the tree and then build your SQL dynamically to perform this even for unknown level of hierarchy.

Comment: Another thing to note is: are you sure that your recursion condition `a.kcode > b.kcode` is working properly? Shouldn't it be `a.kcode < b.kcode` instead?

Comment: please share your table structure, sample data & results *as text*, *not images*

Comment: Your SQL code runs without any problems producing the expected result :O

Answer (score 1):

Recursive WITH is now supported in Snowflake.

Your query

```
WITH RECURSIVE RECURTEMP(ID,KCODE,LVL) AS(
SELECT 
  ID, 
  MIN(KCODE) AS KCODE,
  1
FROM 
  TABLE_A
GROUP BY
  1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  b.ID, 
  trim(a.KCODE) || ';' || trim(b.KCODE)  AS KCODE, 
  LVL+1
FROM 
  TABLE_A a
  INNER JOIN RECURTEMP b ON (a.ID = b.ID AND a.KCODE > b.KCODE)
)
SELECT * FROM RECURTEMP
```

Link to article is below.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/queries-cte.html#overview-of-recursive-cte-syntax